# Facebook Graph API Returning Empty Data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am tring to get facebook friend list but I am getting response null. I am using javascript sdk. Addition In summary I am getting friend's number. But not getting there data.

Here is my code:-

```
FB.init({
    appId      : '{app-id}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v1.0' // use version 2.2
});
function testAPI() {
    FB.login(function(response){
        FB.api("/me/friends", function (response) { 
            console.log(response);
        });
    },{scope: 'user_friends'});
//  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello, world!'}, function(){
        //  console.log(response);
//  });
}

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-auto-logout-link="true"></fb:login-button>
```

can anyone tell me, where I am making mistake?

Comment: Show the complete relevant code!

Comment: You are aware that your app will only be able to see friends of the current user, that are a) users of the same app as well, and b) have also granted `user_friends` permission … right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you FB.init() correctly ?

Did you add correct permissions to your app in developer.facebook page ?

Then you miss some informations like which fields you want in friends list and scope:

```
     FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'XXXXX'}, function(response) {
               console.log(response);
            });
        } else
        {
            console.log('Authorization failed.');
        }
     },{scope: 'friends'});
```

Comment: no it is not working, I think something worng with permission, I will look at developer.facebook page

Comment: Be careful on your test ! If your friend desactivates in his profile the option "Share phone number", you will not receive it by Graph API call !

Comment: First I am not getting data at first place

Comment: @KévinNaudin That's not true about the phone number. This has nothing to do with the API

Answer (score 0):

You'll never be able to get the phone number of your friends, because they are not exposed via the Graph API. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading

Furthermore, you should stick to the examples in the Fb docs, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.4

Sample code copied from FB:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.4' // use version 2.4
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,friends', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using similar code but when I updated my code i am not getting value.

Comment: You don't show a useful portion of your code, so nobody will be really able to help you. Example: Where the `testAPI()` function called? Nobody knows. Why don't you use the sample code I gave you and try that? You only need to replace `{your-app-id}` by your own app's id. I hope you did that in your code?

Comment: testAPI() call when user successfully login, and I already have app-id

Comment: Ok, I'll stop here. Show relevant code, or you'll probably not get your question answered, That's useless

Answer (score 0):

On Android SDK you must add permisions like

```
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_friends"));
```

good programing.

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'id, name, picture'},

function(response) {

console.log(response);

});

Comment: PleaseTry This                                                                                  FB.api("<user-id>/friends?fields=id, name, picture", function (response) {
       console.log(response);
});

Comment: Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.ow only returns friends who also use your app

Comment: So I cant get friend list untill my friend use app? Am I right? Is there any alternative to get list?

Comment: I'm not sure but try this following step  MyApps -> Roles -> Add Testers   Once added you will get user list in api response